# Is plaintiff responsibility to 'mitigate their damages' a law?

Tags: contract-law

Watching the People's Court, the judge says the plaintiff has a responsibility to mitigate their damages.

In other words the (People's) court holds the plaintiff to a standard of effort when they have lost money and are suing to get the money back.

My question, is this standard in the (People's) court part of contract law, or is it a legal standard the court uses in the administration of the law --and possibly open to (greatest) judicial interpretation? Or is it some reasonableness made up for television?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: United States it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duty to mitigate damages is a common law principle, established by case law, that applies in almost all lawsuits seeking money damages in every U.S. jurisdiction. It is not made up for television.

It is part of the substantive law of damages in contract, tort and other other kinds of common law suits and is applied to statutory claims for compensatory damages as well in most circumstances.

All forms of law are open to interpretation in light of the facts and circumstances. In some situations, it may be very clear what steps were necessary to mitigate damages. In others, it may be quite unclear, although case law often provides meaningful guidance on this question in particular kinds of fact patterns.

Comment: I think this is the clearest statement of an answer: _"...is a common law principle, established by case law..."_

Answer (score 0):

It applies in all cases, including torts against the person. It is the concept that you are not allowed to. It is based on the concept that you are not entitled to “do nothing” to fix a situation regardless of who caused it.

Example: you rent an apartment to a tenant and after a couple months, he breaks the lease. You are entitled to sue him for the breach of the contract. However, if you dont make a reasonable effort to find another tenant to replace him, you may not be able to collect from him the entirety of the lease he broke because you did not take action to mitigate the damages he caused.

One more: Someone attacks you and you suffer a broken leg. If you refduse medical treatment, get an infection in your leg and must have it amputated, it is possible the attacker will be responsible only for the initial injury and not the resulting infection because you refused to mitigate the damages caused by his tort against you.

Comment: I may not be using the right language to describe this. But if it's not a law to make an effort, then what sort of standard is it?? Where does this reside in the literature?

Comment: In a common law system, which the United States is because our laws come not only from legislatures and the Congress, but also from the courts, it is not necessary there be a written and passed law in the way you're imagining a bill working it's way through the legislative process. The principle of mitigation of damages is one that has been regularly used by the courts. I wasn't able to find a proper history of the doctrine, but I know it started in contract law and has been applied widely since.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the basic difference between a common law country and a civil law one: The main difference between the two systems is that in common law countries, case law — in the form of published judicial opinions — is of primary importance, whereas in civil law systems, codified statutes predominate. From: https://onlinelaw.wustl.edu/blog/common-law-vs-civil-law/.

Comment: Regrettably, the other person answering this question seems to have deleted their answer. In my follow-up I asked, Is failure to provide 'notice' an example of laws governing 'negligence'? And importantly, Do you know of an online resource to find case law for NYS 'contract' & 'negligence' cases? Do you have any answers to these questions?

Comment: @xtian One of the down sides of the common law country system based upon case law is that it is very hard for a non-lawyer without a legal education and access to legal research resources which are often expensive to do meaningful legal research on questions like this. Failure to provide notice can give rise to torts such as product liability and negligence. Books such as the "Nutshell Series" on legal topics available in many college bookstores or outlines for law students might be a good place to start.

Comment: Nutshell series is pretty solid, indeed. But also, check nolo.com, findlaw, and, honestly, Wikipedia has extensive sections on every area of law. As to your question about notice and negligence, it all depends on the circumstances. For example, if you are a landowner and there is a trespasser on your property, you have no duty to notify him of a visible danger but you are required to notify him of any latent dangers. But, notice is a thing in nearly every law topic you can think of, from the notice required when you file a suit to the notice implied by recording a land deed @xtian

Comment: I will look into the recommendations. In my county, I can access the court library, and legal databases. Curiously, I had the opposite experience. When I researched a contract dispute in this library, I found the legal texts very difficult to work with. But in an unrelated experience, I found a database of California case law and successfully argued a case was sufficiently similar to win my case. The law is not my gig, but I believe strongly in small claims people have a right to reasonable information to help their case.

Comment: I think @ohwilleke is referencing tools such as Westlaw and LexisNexis. The tools I suggested are certainly easily accessible but they are similar in my mind to shareware apps free vs. pro versions. The free versions are for everyone and can certainly help you out. But the paid version, while not meant for everyone, is absolutely necessary for the pros in that space :)

Comment: One more item in support of case law databases for small claims. I refer to the Peoples Court in my question, and it's the example that proves the point--people's small claims cases are easy to relate to and understand. And if the show is at all representative of one's community, then many cases are variations on only a few themes. Surely some enterprising person has made a book of the most useful cases? Wiki-caselaw? The trick, and why I pursued the terms and their proper categories, is you can't find much unless you know the legal terms that structure the content--case law or other.

Comment: Try the resources at http://guides.library.harvard.edu/free. Also, try https://www.lexisweb.com.